# Video-Codecs in Chromium missing

Tags: video, chromium, mp4, codec

I use a Version 81.0.4032.0 (Entwickler-Build) (64-Bit) Chromium Browser on my Windows 10 computer.
On Facebook Videos and some Gifs are not running. So I opened the Console and found this logs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42C01E"') is unsupported.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.5"') is unsupported.
```

I have checked with this site: https://w3c-test.org/media-source/mediasource-is-type-supported.html and got 11 failed tests.

How can I add the missing codecs to chromium?

UPDATE list of **failed** tests:
Test invalid MIME format "audio/webm;aaacodecsbbb=opus"               
Test valid WebM type "audio/webm;codecs=vorbis;test="6""              
Test valid MP4 type "video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4d001e""                  
Test valid MP4 type "video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42001e""                  
Test valid MP4 type "audio/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.2""                    
Test valid MP4 type "audio/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.5""                    
Test valid MP4 type "audio/mp4;codecs="mp4a.67""                      
Test valid MP4 type "video/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.2""                    
Test valid MP4 type "video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4d001e,mp4a.40.2""        
Test valid MP4 type "video/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.2 , avc1.4d001e ""     
Test valid MP4 type "video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4d001e,mp4a.40.5""

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Super User. Could you possibly edit your post to include the tests that failed on that w3c test? That could potentially help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Chromium does not support proprietary codecs (like h.264, aac). Official info: https://www.chromium.org/audio-video

So, on macOS, you need to compile Chromium with the proprietary codecs support  yourself ; or download pre-compiled versions with the proprietary codecs support (https://chromium.woolyss.com/ - I am the admin of this website for many years).